# Are Thai visa extensions effectively suspended because of the protests?

Tags: visas, thailand, bangkok

On the [Thailand immigration website](http://immigration.go.th/), it says that immigration services are suspended at the main office because of the protests:

> Due to the demonstrations, Immigration services provided at Government Complex Center are suspended

It looks like they set up some temporary offices in the meantime though:

> Our temporary offices are :
>
> 1. Immigration Service Center for 3 national Legalized Labors, Major Hollywood Suksawat, 1st Floor, Suksawat Road, Ratburana, Bangkok. Click here to view a map
> 2. Immigration Service Center for 3 national Legalized Labors, Imperial World Ladprao, 5th Floor, Ladprao Road, Wang Tong Lang, Bangkok. Click here to view a map
>
> This temporary service will be started from January 13rd, 2014 until the situation improves. We apologise for inconvenience. Service time Mon-Fri 10:30 - 18:30 Closed on OFFICIAL HOLIDAYS

The temporary offices probably are "officially" handling visa extensions, but I wonder if the relocation is causing enough disruption/delay that it would be a waste of my time to try to get my VoA extended.

Is it still possible to get a visa on arrival extended at one of the temporary immigration offices?  How much longer does it take than it used to at the central office?

Comment: According to DSBKK, it looks like the answer is, "Nope!  Business as usual!"  https://www.facebook.com/groups/DSBKK/permalink/645880402132933/?stream_ref=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're still accepting the extension applications at temporary centres, see [this Lonely Planet forum thread](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/asia-thailand/topics/visa-extension-in-bangkok-0a3cf89c-909c-4b56-a102-c1fe7ac47d61).

I can't comment on how long it will take though as I haven't done it myself.